# Playframework Accept version routing

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I am trying to implement REST versioning in Play 2.2.

I expect the client to send the following in the header:

```
Accept: application/vnd.helloworld+json; version=1
```

And based on that version header, the server will call the matching controller action. I plan to snapshot a complete controller package for each version of the api.

Something like this:

```
com.helloworld.v1.controllers
com.helloworld.v2.controllers
```

For example:

```
POST /users/login
{ "email": "foo@gmail.com", "password": "bar" }
```

I would like to direct that request to the following controller:

```
com.helloworld.v1.controllers.UserController
```

How can I *cleanly* accomplish that in **Global.onRouteRequest**?

Comment: Are the URLs easily interchangeable?

Comment: It's possible that there is additional routes in subsequent version of the api, and that the api could have different parameters between versions.

Comment: I mean like regex replacing `v1` for `v2` in the request URI.

Comment: There won't be a v1 or v2 from the perspective of the client. We're trying to implement this spec: https://github.com/interagent/http-api-design#version-with-accepts-header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After thinking about this for awhile I'm having a hard time imagining this working the way you describe without using runtime reflection to call package/classes by version. I'd also be weary of doing it that way, as you say your API versions may have different parameters, which would make the types incompatible.

Here's a way to do it by defining the default API URI in your routes, then a URI for each version. In `onRouteRequest` you can re-route the incoming request to a different URI, (without using a `Redirect`) and it will remain unknown to the user that those other URIs exist. Note that query parameters are needed to allow them to pass through the default url (if the types are going to be changing, I don't think there's another way).

Routes:

```
GET     /api                        controllers.Application.index
GET     /v1/api                     controllers.v1.Test.index(test: Int ?= 0)
GET     /v2/api                     controllers.v2.Test.index(test: String ?= "")
```

In the `GlobalSettings` object:

```
override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
    // Strip the version from the headers
    val regex = "version=(\\d+)".r
    val version: Option[Int] = request.headers.get("Accept").flatMap(x => regex.findFirstMatchIn(x).map(_.group(1).toInt))

    // Copy the version to the URI (if found) in a new RequestHeader (if found), and re-route
    val req: RequestHeader = version.map(v => 
        request.copy(
            uri = "/v" + v.toString + request.uri, 
            path = "/v" + v.toString + request.path
        ) 
    ).getOrElse(request)

    super.onRouteRequest(req)
}
```

The only part of this solution I consider unclean is the necessity for enumerated routes, which will be difficult to overcome considering the code gymnastics the reverse routes compiler normally does.

Comment: I agree, this is probably the best way. Enumerating the version routes doesn't bother me that much, maybe split the routes and import each version routes with a prefix in the main route file. This solution preserves all the work that the reverse router does which is nice

Comment: @JamesCowhen "maybe split the routes and import each version routes with a prefix in the main route file" - How would it be done? I'm facing the same problem.